# Flash Builder and iOS

Tags: apache-flex, ios, flex4, flash-builder, flex4.5

I have download Flash Builder 4.5.

When I install it, I also check 'Air for Apple iOS support' to install it too.

But when I create a new Flex Mobile Application, at the second page, I can chose the Platform Target be I just have Android and not iOS.

What do I have to do to create a iOS application?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS is not supported with Flex Mobile Projects in the current builds of Flash Builder 4.5.

According to the [Adobe keynote](http://zaa.tv/2011/04/360flex-denver-2011-day-1-keynote/) given at 360|Flex Denver, an update will be provided in June that will allow for targeting of iOS and Blackberry Playbook with Flex projects.

I believe you should be able to target iOS in ActionScript only projects.

---

It has been a long time passed since I answered this question.  Current version of Flash Builder do indeed support targeting iOS, for both flex projects and ActionScript projects.

Comment: Yes, iOS just in AS project. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can now target iOS in MXML projects. If your install doesn't have the option in the wizard, do these two things:

- Download the latest SDK (4.5.1, currently)
- In Flash Builder, Choose `Help` > `Search for Flash Builder Updates...` from the menus.

The latter should then show the option to install iOS support.